# Creating a Migration for Admin Users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, migration

How do I create a migration file which will create a user with the role of "admin"? I've written the following:

```
rails g migration User
```

How can I give a role of "admin" to this user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migrations may serve two functions:

1. The manipulation of *structure* in your database
2. The manipulation of *data* in your database

Generally speaking it is best practice to use them for the first, and to try to avoid the second (which may cause issues to an upgrade path down the line).

Your question is unclear regarding whether you're asking to create a User table with a column representing administrative privileges, or if you're trying to add an administrative user to an existing Users table.

**If you are trying to create a User table**, you will want to do the following:

```
rails g model users is_administrator:boolean other_column:type
```

Something along these lines will generate a migration (and matching model) allowing Users to be created, with a column containing what could be treated as administrative privileges.

On the other hand, **if you already have a Users table**, and are trying to *add* the ability to distinguish administrators from non-administrators, you would be better suited by something like this:

```
rails g migration add_is_administrator_to_users is_administrator:boolean
```

Finally, **if you are asking how to add a User to the table Users which already exists and contains the column "is_administrator"**, I would encourage you to add the following line to db/seeds.rb:

```
User.create( is_administrator: true, other_column: 'other value' )
```

And then run the following line in the console

```
rake db:seed
```

If this doesn't make sense, I would encourage you to read up in [Active Record Migrations](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html), or (in the case that you choose to leverage the third method) [Active Record Seeds](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#migrations-and-seed-data).

Answer (score 0):

You can have users and admin in same table and add one more column called "role" which will be boolean, which will decide if the current user is admin or not

```
rails g migration user role:boolean name
```

if role is false than it is not an admin.